# Threadpool in python is not as fast as expected

Tags: python, multithreading, machine-learning, feature-extraction

I'm beginner to python and machine learning. I'm trying to reproduce the code for `countvectorizer()` using multi-threading. I'm working with yelp dataset to do sentiment analysis using `LogisticRegression`. This is what I've written so far:

Code snippet:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
from threading import Thread, current_thread
from functools import partial
data = df['text']
rev = df['stars'] 


y = []
def product_helper(args):
    return featureExtraction(*args)


def featureExtraction(p,t):     
    temp = [0] * len(bag_of_words)
    for word in p.split():
        if word in bag_of_words:
            temp[bag_of_words.index(word)] += 1

    return temp


# function to be mapped over
def calculateParallel(threads): 
    pool = ThreadPool(threads)
    job_args = [(item_a, rev[i]) for i, item_a in enumerate(data)]
    l = pool.map(product_helper,job_args)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return l

temp_X = calculateParallel(12)
```

Here this is just part of code.

Explanation:

`df['text']` has all the reviews and `df['stars']` has the ratings (1 through 5). I'm trying to find the word count vector `temp_X` using multi-threading. `bag_of_words` is a list of some frequent words of choice.

Question:

Without multi-threading , I was able to compute the `temp_X` in around 24 minutes and the above code took 33 mins for a dataset of size 100k reviews. My machine has 128GB of DRAM and 12 cores (6 physical cores with hyperthreading i.e., threads per core=2).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your whole code seems `CPU Bound` rather than `IO Bound`.You are just using `threads` which are under `GIL` so effectively running just one thread plus overheads.It runs only on one core.To run on multiple cores use

Use

```
import multiprocessing
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
l = pool.map_async(product_helper,job_args)
```

from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool is just a wrapper over `thread` module.It utilises just `one core` and not more than that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have more question here. Where are we specifying the number of cores to use?

Comment: @bhaskarjupudi it will pick the no of cores available.....from multiprocessing.cpu_count() automatically

Comment: Here in the code snippet that you posted, l is an object. How to retrieve the actual list from that object?

Comment: @bhaskarjupudi just loop over l and try i.get or simply i

Answer (score 1):

Python and threads dont really work together very well. There is a known issue called the GIL (global interperter lock). Basically there is a lock in the interperter that makes all threads not run in parallel (even if you have multiple cpu cores). Python will simply give each thread a few milliseconds of cpu time one after another (and the reason it became slower is the overhead from context switching between those threads).

Here is a really good document explaining how it works: http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf

To fix your problem i suggest you try multi processing:
https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html

Note: multiprocessing is not 100% equivilent to multithreading. Multiprocessing will run at parallel but the diffrent processes wont share memory so if you change a variable in one of them it will not be changed in the other process.